# Does NTLM Authentication no longer work with the latest Postman native app 6.0.10

Tags: windows, authentication, authorization, postman, ntlm

I keep getting 401 Forbidden response testing our IIS based WebAPI calls using  my Windows credentials in Postman version 6.0.10. Is there a workaround for this in Postman without using a hack like running Fiddler as a proxy in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try without the ssl certificate. 
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/launching_postman/settings

Comment: Thanks but I'm using http not https in my API calls

Comment: postman 8.2.3 + NTLM authentication + IIS 8 does not work at all. IIS always return 401 error with any settings